# EC2 - accessing instance without elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Since I don't need to reserve an IP address with Elastic IP (I'm testing for now), I'm just using the Public IP randomly assigned at every startup.

After setting up a game server via SSH and opening the related ports on the Security Group, said server is not reachable.

Testing further I've noticed that the instance is not even answering ping request (yes, I've added relative rules in the Security Group).

So the instance is working only on port 22, can anyone explain why?

Here are the Security Group rules:

```
Ports       Protocol   Source
0--1        icmp       0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
22          tcp        0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
7787-7788   udp        0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
27166       tcp        0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
27165-27166 udp        0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
```

EDIT2 adding ACL inbound rules:

```
Rule # Type        Protocol Port Range Source     Allow / Deny
100    ALL Traffic ALL      ALL        0.0.0.0/0  ALLOW
```

Comment: Did you eventually find out why the ec2 instance is not answering your ping requests? Did the ip address change?

Comment: Is your EC2 in a subnet with an ACL preventing pings? Is there any other configuration associated with this EC2? Can you post the security group settings in your question?

Comment: Does your EC2 instance have public DNS or private IP ? Please write about it.

Comment: @Milk, where can i verify if the ACL is preventing pings? I have added my security group configuration. there is no other config on my side, this instance is brand new

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to SSH to the instance, then the problem is not related to the network configuration.

The NACL configuration you show permits all traffic.

That leaves the instance as the guilty party, so you should concentrate your efforts on-instance rather than elsewhere.

Comment: so i have to enable ping on the instance?

Comment: PING is merely used as a diagnostic method to debug connectivity problems. You should concentrate on enabling connectivity to your application. If you disagree and would rather get PING to work, then I would recommend launching a fresh EC2 instance in the same subnet with the same Security Group, getting PING to work, and then comparing the configuration difference between the two instances.

Comment: Yes, I would like to see pings working to be absolutely sure that there are no connectivity issues! I have started a vanilla instance and tried to ping it, still no responses..

Comment: @RenatoStretti if you can connect over `ssh` what additional value is `ping` going to provide you? I would concentrate on the ports your application runs on, like making sure the application is listening to all traffic not just localhost traffic, and making sure any firewalls on the server like `iptables` are configured to allow traffic on your application port.

Answer (score 0):

So i found what was wrong: the icmp rule I was setting inbound was for *icmp echo reply*, i had to use **icmp echo request**, it took me 8 hours to realize it. no need to configure iptaples, ACL or else.

I'm sorry for the useless thread!